# Migrating an ORM based Spring project (Hibernate / JPA) to noSQL (MongoDB/Cassandra/CauchDB)

Tags: jpa, nosql

I am fairly new to the noSQL world, and although I understand the benefits of performance and "cloud" friendliness, it seems the RDBMS world is much simpler and standard and limited to fewer players

I worked with SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, Sybase, Terradata, MySQL and others, and it seems they have in common much more (in terms of Query language, Indexing, ACID, etc) than the noSQL family.

My question is mainly this

1. Is it at all a valid concept to move an existing Spring/Java EE+JPA app to a noSQL storage? or it will require a complete re-architecture of the system beyond the medium of storage?
2. Hoping it's a valid goal, are there any migration paths that were case studied as best practices?
3. Is there an equivalent to the concept in "noSQL" that is comparable to ORM for RDBMS?  e.g. any layer of separating the storage implementation from concept (I know GAE BigTable supports JDO and JPA but only partially, is there a newer JSR for a more noSQL friendly JPA?)
4. Are there any attempts to standardize "noSQL" the same way RDBMS are (query language, 
   API)
5. Is "noSQL" a too wide term? Should I modify the question per implementation (KV/Document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataNucleus allows JPA persistence to RDBMS, MongoDB, HBase and various others. That is one way you can tackle the problem, giving you a start point for use of your app with other datastores. From there you could modify class hierarchies to get around some of the problems that these other datastores bring. Use of JPA with other datastores is not part of any JSR and never will be, since JPA is designed around RDBMS solely. JDO on the other hand is already a standard for all datastores, as it was designed to be (also supported by DataNucleus)

Comment: Saying JPA will never support NoSQL is very obstinate, never say never.  Especially considering there are so many NoSQL JPA solutions out there, far more than NoSQL JDO solutions.

Comment: Ahh, more downvotes from the Oracle staff :-) have a nice day

Answer (score 3):

Try Kundera : https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera. it is an open source JPA2.0 compliant solution. You can also join http://groups.google.com/group/kundera-discuss/subscribe for further discussion.

-Vivek

Answer (score 1):

EclipseLink 2.4 supports JPA with MongoDB and other NoSQL data sources.

http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2012/04/eclipselink-jpa-supports-mongodb.html

Answer (score 1):

PlayOrm is another solution with it's Scalable-SQL and is JPA-like but breaks from JPA in that it supports noSQL patterns that JPA can't support.